# Htaccess Redirect with domain attributes

Tags: .htaccess

I have to write a redirect rule for the below condition.

`www.domain.com/custom.aspx?ATTR=VALUE` to 
`www.domain.com/custom?ATTR=VALUE`

How can this be achieved using the .htaccess

I have the below set of codes using on the current .htaccess file. Please also suggest where to include your code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using mod_rewrite, eg something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes! I am using the mod_rewrite. But using the above rule lead me to the 404 page.

Comment: Do you mean that your browser gets properly redirected to www.domain.com/custom?ATTR=VALUE, but that URL returns a 404? If so, then why would you want to redirect there?

Comment: No redirection is happening here. My page stays at `www.domain.com/custom.aspx?ATTR=VALUE`

Comment: I may have been a bit too quick, I just updated my answer. Could you try that variation instead?

Comment: The result is same. The page is not redirecting. I have edited my question with the current .htaccess file. Please check these as well.

Comment: Where did you place my additional RewriteRule? If I am not mistaken, your last rule matches just about anything that would result in a 404 and disables any further rewrite processing. It seems that /custom.aspx?ATTR=VALUE would match that rule as well. Does your index.php file exist?

Comment: This works after I added my code after `RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]` line